# Error 102 in PayPal Manager

Tags: paypal

I'm looking to use a PayPal hosted Gateway page to accept payments for a site I'm working on (based in the UK)

After a lot of difficulty, I've managed to set up an test-only Payflow account using this guide: https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/pp_integrations_preston/testing-paypal-payflow-gateway

But when I log in and try and change the hosted checkout settings to "test", I'm getting:

```
"Error: 102 error content"
```

and no settings will update.

I can find anyone else who's seeing this same error message, but PayPal's documentation doesn't mention this error in the manager, but says that error 102 with transactions is the payment processor not being available - so I think there's a chance it's that.

The guide I used to set up the account only linked to a US version of the registration page, so I just changed the countrycode parameter in the query string attached to the link so I could use a UK address, but the Payment Processors all seem to be based in the US, I've tried 2 different ones (FDMS Nashville and WorldPay) and I'm getting the same error on both.

I've had so many problems trying to set this up, I've been reading various guide and the official documentation solidly for 3 days and haven't even opened my IDE yet - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have link to your checkout that you can provide, so that we could walk through and test it and see what the issue may be?  It's hard to see say what the issue is at this point, with out seeing what you are passing over, where at specifically the error is getting generated at during the checkout, and without knowing how your account is set up.

Comment: Hi Chad, apologies for the delay in getting back. It turns out that Payflow Link isn't available in the UK - though Paypal's developer documentation didn't make this particularly clear. Once I knew I needed to use Express Checkout instead, I got my problem resolved.

Thanks for answering though!